# Node.js + MongoDB: insert one and return the newly inserted document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm wondering if there is a way to insert new document and return it in one go.

This is what I'm currently using:

```
db.collection('mycollection').insertOne(options, function (error, response) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by returning the new one? You want the response from insertOne to be a document with **_id**?

Comment: no you cannot. insert method just return the acknowledgement that a document is inserted successfully. you cannot combine two actions into one. you have to fire a find() again after insert()

Answer (score 102, accepted):

---

**UPDATE 2021:** This approach **no longer works** with the MongoDB driver **4.x.** The return result of the insertOne only contains an ID and acknowledgement flag: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html

With this change, there is NO way to accomplish the required behaviour. One should either do another DB request or combine the returned insertId and original object data.

---

The `response` result contains information about whether the command was successful or not and the number of records inserted.

If you want to return inserted data, you can try `response.ops`, for example:

```
db.collection('mycollection').insertOne(doc, function (error, response) {
    if(error) {
        console.log('Error occurred while inserting');
       // return 
    } else {
       console.log('inserted record', response.ops[0]);
      // return 
    }
});
```

Official documentation for `insertOne`:

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#insertOne

The `callback` type:

[http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpCallback](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#%7EinsertOneWriteOpCallback)

The `result` type:

[http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#~insertOneWriteOpResult](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#%7EinsertOneWriteOpResult)

Comment: It worked! But it's kind of weird that when I do `console.log(response)` the `ops` doesn't show up!

Comment: it has to do with when the value is evaluated.

Comment: Thanks! It is documented on teh github page for `mongodb` driver for `node` in the section [insert a document](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#insert-a-document). From the docs: `ops - Contains the documents inserted with added _id fields`.

Comment: whats wierd is sometimes documentation suggests deprecated methods, then the terminal gives a warning, it seems stackoverflow has more updated code

Comment: This answer is correct, though I'm not sure why `ops` is an array when the method is supposed to insert only one document.

Comment: seems like in version 4 it's not possible to get the created document back. Very inconvenient change.

Comment: "NO way to accomplish the required behaviour".  Fake news (or perhaps just outdated news here in 2022).  See `findOneAndUpdate` with the `upsert` option. Answer by renen

Answer (score 11):

For those who use **MongoDB driver 4.x** I found a workaround with [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/classes/collection.html#findoneandupdate):

```js
      const toInsert = {
        _id: mongo.ObjectId(),
        someField: 'hello',
        someOtherField: 'world'
      };
      const options = { upsert: true, returnDocument: 'after' };
      const { value: document } = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        toInsert,
        { $set: {} },
        options
      );
```

Notice that the `_id` in `toInsert` is a newly generated `ObjectId`.

The update is empty (`{ $set: {} }`) and does nothing as we don't need to need to update, we just want to upsert our document. It's still needed because the update cant be `null` or an empty object.

Because of the `returnDocument` option, the newly created document will be return as value in the result.

---

An other solution, in order to avoid an empty update, is to use `$setOnInsert`:

```js
      const toInsert = { someField: 'hello', someOtherField: 'world' };
      const options = { upsert: true, returnDocument: 'after' };
      const { value: document } = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: mongo.ObjectId() },
        { $setOnInsert: toInsert },
        options
      );
```

Comment: This works if you don't need to track creation date

Answer (score 5):

The following code worked for me, in **MongoDB version 2.2.33.**

```
db.collection("sample_collection").insertOne({
   field1: "abcde"
}, (err, result) => {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(result.ops[0].field1)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can return the doc that you insert with the id

```
async insertProduct(product) {
  const record = await db.collection("products").insertOne(product);
  return {id: record.insertedId, ...product }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to do this. With the `save` method you can insert a document and return it on success. Here is an example from the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save):

```js
product.save(function (err, product, numAffected) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error...
  } else {
    // Do something with the returned document...
  }
})
```

Comment: in case the doc is already there, it will return it. not the new one

Comment: This approach no longer works with the MongoDB driver 4.x. The return of the insertOne only contains an ID and acknowledgement flag

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as this might be helpful for someone. You can find the updated object like this:

```
await req.db
    .collection('users')
    .insertOne({ email, password: hashedPassword, name  })
    .then(({ ops }) => ops[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Latest v4 behaviour

As [Lauren said](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/did-insertone-in-node-js-v4-change-to-not-return-the-inserted-doc/120254/2) in official mongodb forum, this is the expected behaviour. I copy here her response:

> It is new in driver v4 that our driver is compliant with the MongoDB
> CRUD spec
>
> When you `insertOne` you now get the `insertedId`, so that should provide
> the only “new” part of the document that’s handled by the database.

```js
    const myDoc = { a: 1 }
    myDoc._id = (await c.insertOne(myDoc)).insertedId
    // myDoc is now the same as the doc inserted into mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) to do this.

```
db.collection('mycollection').save(doc, function(error, response){
  // response has _id
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
try {
    let collection = db.collection('collection_name'); let { ops: inserted } = 
    await collection.insertOne({ data: object });
    // can access array of inserted record like :
    console.log(inserted)
 } catch (error) {
    // log errors
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2021: This approach no longer works with the MongoDB driver 4.x. The return of the insertOne only contains an ID and acknowledgement flag**

I wanted to still use .then() to resolve by insert so I ended up wrapping the everything in it's own promise.

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     db.collection('entries').insertOne({ entry }, (err, res) => {
     if (err) {
       console.log('error', err);
       reject(null);
     } else {
       resolve(res.ops[0]);
     }
   });
 });
```

then I could just do

```
 insertEntry({}).then(entry=>{})
```

Comment: This is no longer supported with the Node driver 4.x