# How to fix the Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my function.
Showing error on resolve(data.ops[0])

```
var db = require("../config/connection")
var collection = require("../config/collection")
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
module.exports={
    doSignup:(userData)=>{
        return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
            userData.Password =await bcrypt.hash(userData.Password,10)
           db.get().collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION).insertOne(userData).then((data)=>{
               resolve(data.ops[0])
           })
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js + MongoDB: insert one and return the newly inserted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766654/node-js-mongodb-insert-one-and-return-the-newly-inserted-document)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Mongodb are you into?

Cause the new versions don't have an property called `ops` and that's why `resolve(data.ops[0])` gives an error what you see.

Looking at the documentation below it returns a `InsertOneResult`

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#insertOne

```
insertOne(doc: OptionalId<TSchema>): Promise<InsertOneResult<TSchema>>
```

If you see the document of same https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html

It returns `acknowledged` and `insertedid`. Thus the below works

```
resolve(data.insertedId)
```