# TypeError: Error Cannot read property '0' of undefined when returning a response from chatbot

Tags: javascript, mongoose, dialogflow-es

I'm currently working on an API for my chatbot that saves user input to my database. It works fine when I do queries and it saves to my database without any problems. My problem is that it should send a response that it got the user query.

Here's my code for the route/controller:

```
if (req.body.queryResult.parameters.informationType == "appointment") {
    const user = {
        firstName: req.body.queryResult.parameters.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.queryResult.parameters.lastName,
        mobile: req.body.queryResult.parameters.mobile,
        email: req.body.queryResult.parameters.email,
        status: "Pending",
        informationType: req.body.queryResult.parameters.informationType,
        appointmentDate: dateToISO(req.body.queryResult.parameters.appointmentDate),
        };

        db.db()
        .collection("users")
        .insertOne(user, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    "fulfillmentText": "Error has occured. Cannot add user.",
                 });
            } else {
                var firstName = result.ops[0].firstName;
                var lastName = result.ops[0].lastName;

                return res.json({
                    "fulfillmentText":
                            "Okay, got it " +
                            firstName +
                            " " +
                            lastName +
                            ". We will send an email or text message from the contact info you have provided once your appointment has been approved.",
                });
            }
        })
}
```

Also, here's its model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  appointmentDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  informationType: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("users", user);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I stumbled upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766654/node-js-mongodb-insert-one-and-return-the-newly-inserted-document) and read some [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/interfaces/InsertOneResult.html). Apparently, the approach that I used doesn't work anymore.

After hours of trying and scouring various post, I finally found the solution (which was actually a no-brainer). This is what I did:

```
var firstName = req.body.queryResult.parameters.firstName;
var lastName = req.body.queryResult.parameters.lastName;
```